# parse error: syntax error: unexpected '}'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Having a small problem with the error in the title, however all the brackets match up so I don't know why its displaying this error. Anyone see why?

Code is:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'db/connect.php';
    //require_once 'entryformsuccess.php';
    echo $_SESSION['Username'] . ' logged in successfully ' . ' <br> ';

        if ($student_delete = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Forename, Surname, Student_ID, Username " .
                                            "FROM student, teacher " . 
                                                "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")) {

            if (isset($_POST['Student_ID']))    {   
                $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; 

                for ($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++) {
                    $del_student = $checkbox[$i];
                    $query= $con->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE Student_ID = 'Student_ID'")


                }                           

            }
        }       

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `;` at the end of

```
$query= $con->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE Student_ID = 'Student_ID'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update it.

```
<?php

        session_start();
        require_once 'db/connect.php';
        //require_once 'entryformsuccess.php';
        echo $_SESSION['Username'] . ' logged in successfully ' . ' <br> ';

            if ($student_delete = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Forename, Surname, Student_ID, Username " .
                                                "FROM student, teacher " . 
                                                    "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")) {

                if (isset($_POST['Student_ID']))    {   
                    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; 

                    for ($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++) {
                        $del_student = $checkbox[$i];
                        $query= $con->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE Student_ID = 'Student_ID'");


                    }                           

                }
            }       

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
$query= $con->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE Student_ID = 'Student_ID'");
```